# Cycle notation question

Tags: notation, permutations

With $\alpha = (12345)$ in the cycle notation, I should interpret it as:

$1\mapsto 2 \mapsto 3\mapsto 4\mapsto 5\mapsto 1$

I need to find out $\alpha^2$ and write it in cyclic notation. As I am not quite apt at it, I used the two row notation to solve it:

$$\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So  $$\alpha ^2  = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

The answer provided is $\alpha^2 = (13524)$. Similarly, the answers to $\alpha^3$ etc were not matching. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're answer is the same as the one provided. Also $\alpha^3 = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 4 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{smallmatrix}\right) = (14253)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong; your answer agrees with the book's answer:

$$\alpha^2 = (13524)$$

means that $\alpha^2$ acts by

$$1\mapsto 3 \mapsto 5\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto 1$$

which is precisely what the two-column form

$$\alpha ^2  = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

says (or rather, it says $1\mapsto 3$ and $2\mapsto 4$ and $3\mapsto 5$ and $4\mapsto 1$ and $5\mapsto 2$, which we simplify by writing $1\mapsto 3 \mapsto 5\mapsto 2\mapsto 4\mapsto 1$).

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. I feel silly now.

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us :)